# how can I capture the argument with a certain word

Tags: python, string, startswith

In my code below, I used startswith() method to find out if an argument has word "sales" in it or not. However, it only checks if it starts with the word. How can I capture all the argument that has word "sales" in it? (regardless starts with, ends with, or in the middle)

```
def isSales(job):
    a = job.lower()
    if a.startswith('sales'):
        return 'True'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

'startswith' as the name says it only checks at the beginning.

```
def isSales(job):
    a = job.lower()
    if 'sales' in a:
        return 'True'
```

Comment: Please don't answer blatant duplicates.